# display sales through sql query after subtracting sales return of same product and bill number

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a table(sales) in my database which records sales and sale return. [image]

sale returns are recorded with the `status='sr'`
I want to display final quantity of each product after deducting the sale returns.
example for the product `B0801180323NA` there is a sales return with `quantity:2` and also sale with `quantity:2` so the final quantity which has to be displayed now is `0`.

Comment: can you have more sales and sale returns per product?

Comment: yes but that will be distinguished by the bill id

Comment: and you want final quantity per product after all these sales and sale returns, right?

Comment: yes, for each `bill_id` and `product` there will be only one sale and one sale return

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: but how can I draw database here using formatted text

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: See my solution below. Works with only one sale / sr as well as multiple. Shows each record per bill_id and then products and doesn't depend on joins or subqueries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT products, SUM(IF(status='sale',quantity,0)) - SUM(IF(status='sr',quantity,0)) AS quantity 
FROM sales
GROUP BY bill_id, products;
```

This counts the quantities based on the 'status' column, subtracting the 'sale' ones from the 'sr' ones.

Comment: You might have to swap 'sale' and 'sr' to your needs, currently 'sr' is subtracted from 'sale'

Comment: Others also given a correct solutions but your solution is very simple. Thanks bro

Answer (score 1):

You could use a join with same table   and differnce on the sum group by products

```
select a.products, sum(a.quantity) -  ifnull(sum(b.quantity),0)
from sales 
left join sales on a.products = b.products and b.status = 'sr'
where a.status = 'sale' 
group by a.products
```

Comment: inull? - i prefer colsce

Comment: is this innull or [isnull](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would use subqueries

```
select products,
       (
          select sum(quantity) from sales s2 where s2.products = s1.products and status = 'sale'
       ) -
       (
          select sum(quantity) from sales s2 where s2.products = s1.products and status = 'sr'
       )
from (select distinct products from sales) s1
```

Comment: Gettig an error in the last line at `select`, that says `This type of clause was previously parsed`

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(a.quantity) - coalesce(sum(b.quantity), 0) as total_quantity, a.bill_id, a.product_id 
from sales a
left join sales b on a.bill_id = b.bill_id and a.product_id = b.product_id
and b.status = 'sr'
where a.status = 'sales'
group by a.bill_id, b.product_id
```